# php shorthand if

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm struggling to understand why the following code is echoing out 'FOO2' when i'm expecting 'FOO1'

```
$tmp = 'foo1';
echo $tmp == 'foo1' ? 'FOO1' : $tmp == 'foo2' ? 'FOO2' : 'NO FOO';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

basically PHP breaks this down to:

```
$tmp = 'foo1';
echo ($tmp == 'foo1' ? 'FOO1' : $tmp == 'foo2') ? 'FOO2' : 'NO FOO';
```

the part in parentheses will return `FOO1` which evaluates to `TRUE` so the second conditional statement essentially is `TRUE ? 'FOO2' : 'NO FOO';` – which in turn always evaluates to `'FOO2'`

Note: This is different from C ternary operator associativity

Answer (score 8):

```
$tmp = 'foo1';
echo $tmp == 'foo1' ? 'FOO1' : ($tmp == 'foo2' ? 'FOO2' : 'NO FOO');
```

Comment: -1 This gives a solution to the problem, but does not explain the reason for the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
$tmp = 'foo1';
if($tmp == 'foo1') echo 'FOO1';
else if($tmp == 'foo2') echo 'FOO2';
```

As you have just found out, ternary operators are a minefield of confusion, especially when you try to <strike>nest</strike> stack them. Don't do it!

**Edit:**
The PHP manual also recommends not stacking ternary operators:-

> It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious:

See example 3 on this page of the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/ternary)

Comment: Down vote away, when he comes to maintaining his code he'll regret doing that. He was confused to start with, how will it look in 3 months time?

Answer (score 0):

```
$tmp = 'foo1';
echo $tmp == 'foo1' ? 'FOO1' : ($tmp == 'foo2' ? 'FOO2' : 'NO FOO');
```